# If $H \subset A$ is open in $A$ in $\tau'$ then $H=G \cap A$ where $G \subset X$ is open in $\tau$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Willard's book we have the definition of topology from family of neighbourhoods, namely:[image]

Suppose that we have a family of neighbourhoods defined in $X$ and consider the topology given by exercise $4E$.

Is it true that $d)\Rightarrow a)$ in the following theorem:
[image]?

It is easy to see that $U \in \tau$ is open iff $U \in \mathscr{U}_x$ for all $x \in U$ and $\mathscr{U}_{x}|_{A}=\{U \cap A: U \in \mathscr{U}_{x}\}$ defines a family of neighbourhoods of $x$ in $A$ if $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$ for all $U \in \mathscr{U}_{x}$.

If $H=G \cap A$, where $G$ is open in $X$ then $G \in \mathscr{U}_{x}$ for all $x \in G$. So, $H=G \cap A \in \mathscr{U}_{x}|_{A}$ for all $x \in G$. In particular, $H \in \mathscr{U}_{x}|_{A}$ for all $x \in H$, since $H \subset G$. Hence, $H$ is open in the topology $\tau'$ induced by $\mathscr{U}_{x}|_{A}$.

**My question:** How to prove the other direction, that is, if $H \subset A$ is open in $A$ in the topology induced by $\mathscr{U}_{x}|_{A}$ then $H=G \cap A$ where $G \subset X$ is open in the topology induced by $\mathscr{U}_{x}$?

Comment: It would be good if you took the time to replace those images with MathJax. It shouldn't take too long, and is beneficial for some users and on reducing website strain

Answer (score 0):

- In Th 6.3 we have statements about relative (induced) topology. This isn't related to the way you define topology. You can define it by pointing all the open sets or by providing the base or subbase or a nhood system or by defining the closed sets or by defining the closure operator. It doesn't matter. You don't need do worry about it proving theorem 6.3.
- No, (d) doesn't imply (a).
- Your considerations are incorrect. It's not true that $U$ is open iff $U\in \mathscr{U}_x$ for all $x\in U$. For example on $\Bbb R$ we can define nhood system $\mathscr{U}_x = \{(x-1/n,x+1/n)\,|\,n\in\Bbb N\}$. These intervals are NOT the only open sets.
- I don't know why you are going to prove (a) from (d). The point (a) goes from the very definition of induced topology.

Comment: I am studying topological vector spaces, where topologies are defined in terms of filters of neighborhoods of the origin, as in Exercise 4E of Willard's book.  Therefore, I have that condition d) is satisfied, I would like to verify that a) is also satisfied.

Comment: What he means writing nhood? Is it an open set or any set with x in its interior? I still don't know why you want to prove it. Since it's true for any topology, it's true for a topological vector spaces.

Comment: Nhood is  of $x$ is a set $U$ which contains an open set $V$ containing $x$. The statement that a set $U$ is open if and only if $U \in \mathscr{U}_{x}$ for all $x \in U$ is in Horváth's book page 72.

Comment: Basically, I'm studying topological concepts through the topology defined from the neighborhood system and I'm trying to recover some classical properties from the topology defined specifying which will be the open subsets.

Comment: I found this book and what I read is: the interior of A is a set of all points x for which there exists a neighbourhood $V\in \mathscr B(x)$ such that $V\subset A$. If the interior of $A$ is equal to $A$ then the set $A$ is open. It's totally different from what you wrote.

Comment: Page 72, line 4: A set is open if and only if it is the neighborhood of each of its points.

Comment: But the definition of nhood on page 71, line -8: A set V is a nhood of $x\in X$ if there exists an open set U such that $x\in U\subset V$. In my opinion the author did a bit of a mess here, because he writes about line 11 that neighbourhoods of $x$ are the sets from the family $\mathscr B(x)$.

Comment: The author is correct, but there are several claims to be proved. In his definition the neighbourhoods of $x$ are the sets from the family $\mathscr{B}(x)$. In Trèves' book we also have the same definition of open sets, in terms of nhoods.